# My items disappear when clicking on sort button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-isotope

So I have an assignment where I have to create an interface for a brand using Isotope. 
I have made some filterbuttons and they all work.
But when I want to use my 'Sort on Price' or 'Name', they just disappear and the Console doesn't give any errors so I'm lost..

Any solutions how to fix this issue?
My Code:

```js
// init Isotope
var iso = new Isotope('.grid', {
  itemSelector: '.element-item',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  getSortData: {
    symbol: '.symbol',
    prijs: '.prijs',
  }
});

// filter functions
var filterFns = {
  // show if the size = size
  numberGreaterThan50: function(itemElem) {
    var size = itemElem.querySelector('.name').textContent;
    return parseInt() === Regular;
  },
};

// bind filter button click
var filtersElem = document.querySelector('.filters-button-group');
filtersElem.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // only work with buttons
  if (!matchesSelector(event.target, 'button')) {
    return;
  }
  var filterValue = event.target.getAttribute('data-filter');
  // use matching filter function
  filterValue = filterFns[filterValue] || filterValue;
  iso.arrange({
    filter: filterValue
  });
});

// change is-checked class on buttons
var buttonGroups = document.querySelectorAll('.button-group');
for (var i = 0, len = buttonGroups.length; i < len; i++) {
  var buttonGroup = buttonGroups[i];
  radioButtonGroup(buttonGroup);
}

function radioButtonGroup(buttonGroup) {
  buttonGroup.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // only work with buttons
    if (!matchesSelector(event.target, 'button')) {
      return;
    }
    buttonGroup.querySelector('.is-checked').classList.remove('is-checked');
    event.target.classList.add('is-checked');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/3.0.6/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <img src="http://logok.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Dominos-pizza-logo-old.png" width="220px" height="160px">
  <h1>Dominos Pizza</h1>
</header>

<div class="container">
  <div class="button-group filters-button-group" id="strook">
    <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">show all products</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".regular">regular</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".medium">medium</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".large">large</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".side-orders">side-orders</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".drinks">drinks</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".symbol">name</button>
    <button class="button" data-filter=".price">price</button>
  </div>

  <div class="grid">
    <div class="element-item regular pizza " data-category="regular">
      <h3 class="name">Regular</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">BBQ Chicken</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€11</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item regular pizza" data-category="regular">
      <h3 class="name">Regular</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">Forestière</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€9</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item regular pizza " data-category="regular">
      <h3 class="name">Regular</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">Cannibale</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€11</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item regular pizza " data-category="regular">
      <h3 class="name">Regular</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">Hot & Spicy</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€11</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item regular pizza " data-category="regular">
      <h3 class="name">Regular</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">4 Stagioni</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€10</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item regular pizza " data-category="regular">
      <h3 class="name">Regular</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">American</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€9</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item medium pizza " data-category="medium">
      <h3 class="name">Medium</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">Gyros</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€12</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item medium pizza " data-category="medium">
      <h3 class="name">Medium</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">Extravaganzza</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€13</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item medium pizza " data-category="medium">
      <h3 class="name">Medium</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">Spicy Chicken</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€13</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item medium pizza " data-category="medium">
      <h3 class="name">Medium</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">Diabolika</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€12</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item medium pizza " data-category="medium">
      <h3 class="name">Medium</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">Veggi</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€12</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item medium pizza " data-category="medium">
      <h3 class="name">Medium</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">Margherita</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€11</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item large pizza " data-category="large">
      <h3 class="name">Large</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">Beef Fanatica</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€17</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item large pizza " data-category="large">
      <h3 class="name">Large</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">Chicken Kebab</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€17</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item large pizza " data-category="large">
      <h3 class="name">Large</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">Tonno</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€17</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item large pizza " data-category="large">
      <h3 class="name">Large</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">Garnalen</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€17</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item large pizza " data-category="large">
      <h3 class="name">Large</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">4 Cheese</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€16</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item large pizza " data-category="large">
      <h3 class="name">Large</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">Hawaiian</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€14</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item side-orders " data-category="side-orders">
      <h3 class="name">Side-order</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">Popcorn Chicken</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€5</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item side-orders " data-category="side-order">
      <h3 class="name">Side-order</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">Cheesy Bread</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€4</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item side-orders " data-category="side-order">
      <h3 class="name">Side-order</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">Buffalo Wings</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€5</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item side-orders " data-category="side-order">
      <h3 class="name">Side-order</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">Potatoe Wedges</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€3,50</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item drinks " data-category="drinks">
      <h3 class="name">Drinks</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">33 Cl Coca-Cola</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€1,50</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item drinks " data-category="drinks">
      <h3 class="name">Drinks</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">33 Cl Coca-Cola Light</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€1,50</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item drinks " data-category="drinks">
      <h3 class="name">Drinks</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">33 Cl Coca-Cola Zero</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€1,50</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item drinks " data-category="drinks">
      <h3 class="name">Drinks</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">33 Cl Fanta</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€1,50</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item drinks " data-category="drinks">
      <h3 class="name">Drinks</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">33 Cl Lipton Ice-Tea</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€1,50</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item drinks " data-category="drinks">
      <h3 class="name">Drinks</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">33 Cl Sprite</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€1,50</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item drinks " data-category="drinks">
      <h3 class="name">Drinks</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">50 Cl Spa Reine</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€1,60</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element-item drinks " data-category="drinks">
      <h3 class="name">Drinks</h3>
      <h4 class="symbol">33 Cl Jupiler Beer</h4>
      <p class="prijs">€1,70</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="photo"></div>
```

Comment: Your filter buttons for **name** and **price** appear to be no different from the others (ie. they’re just removing all elements without the class specified by `data-filter`; so everything)

Comment: Can you give me a good example please?

Comment: There’s a good example in [the documentation](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/sorting.html#ui)